# .NET native framework, runtime, and VCLibs

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-dev-center

I am an app packager, and have been trying to get our first Windows Store app packaged for SCCM.  I have the .appx file for the app that I got with Fiddler, but the app has various dependencies including .NET Native Runtime 1.3, Native Framework 1.3, and VCLibs 14.  I've been pulling my hair out all day trying to get the appx files for these dependencies.  I got one from using Fiddler, and a couple more from installing Visual Studio 2015 community.  However, VS 2015 community came with the 1.4 versions of some of them instead of 1.3, and SCCM did not like that. Is there some place to download these files?  Web searching hasn't given me anything yet.  We don't have windows store for business either so that option is out. This has just been beyond frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some place to download these files?

Based on your description, I’m not sure which appx file you still don’t have currently.

**Updated**:

Since we're never supposed to share the private file at public forum, I have to delete the OneDrive link I provide before.

For this issue, it will be more appropriate to report it to related team and acquire it via the official channel: https://www.visualstudio.com/license-terms/distributable-code-microsoft-visual-studio-2015-rc-microsoft-visual-studio-2015-sdk-rc-includes-utilities-buildserver-files/#universal-windows-apps-and-windows-store-apps

Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Hi Matthew.  Thanks for the OneDrive link, but I also found that same link from previous searches and all those files appear to be the ARM versions.  I just double checked and the one file I am still missing is the x64 .NET Native Runtime 1.3.  I am just surprised Microsoft hasn't made these dependencies easier to get for the non-developer types, since they are pushing universal apps so hard.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I needed.